# Run commands at random

Tags: bash, random

I want to run one of the two commands `C1` and `C2` at random. How do I do that on commandline (bash)? Will appreciate if a one-liner is possible.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
if (( RANDOM % 2 )); then C1; else C2; fi
```

Comment: Bear in mind that if you want a 1 in N odds of running C1, you must probably use `(( RANDOM % N == 0 ))` rather than `(( RANDOM % N ))`. It's only the in special case of N=2 that these have identical probability.

Comment: Plainly put, of what practical use would be `RANDOM % $N` without `== 0`? IMO, for example with N=100, it is much more pragmatic to want a 1 in 100 odds (delivered with `== 0`) than a 99 in 100 odds (delivered without `== 0`).

Answer (score 21):

In your special case:

```
C$((RANDOM%2+1))
```

will work :) And hey, it's the shortest answer!

Comment: Why does it need two sets of parentheses around it?  I am just not very familiar with whatever you used.

Comment: @AJMansfield `$((1+1))` -> `2`, eg. `$(( ))` calculates what's inside.

Comment: It would be even shorter if the OP chose C0 and C1. Maybe he's not a programmer?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that C1 and C2 were placeholders rather than actual commands to run. :-)

Comment: That's cute. +1

Answer (score 6):

You can do something like this in Bash:

```
$ (( RANDOM%2 == 0 )) && C1 || C2
```

This will generate a random number, either 0 or 1. If it's a 0, then C1 runs, otherwise C2 runs if it isn't.

#### example

```
$ (( RANDOM%2 == 0 )) && echo 0 || echo 1
1

$ (( RANDOM%2 == 0 )) && echo 0 || echo 1
0
```

NOTE: The first character, `$`, is the prompt.

#### another example

If you're concerned with C1 having to fail so that C2 can run you could restructure the above like so:

```
(( RANDOM%2 == 0 )) && CMD=C1 || CMD=C2
$CMD
```

#### why use this over a if/then statement?

This answer has been criticized a bit but there's a method to my madness. Though this pattern may seem more obscure than a if/then I find it more readable and compact when doing something like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
CMD=""
DIRS="/etc /home /www /data1 /data2 /var/log /var/spool/mail"
FILE="/backup/$(hostname)-$(date +'%m-%d-%y').tar.gz"
[ "$1" == "nas" ]  && CMD="lftp -u user,password -e 'cd /dump/; mput /backup/*; quit' nas.mylan.com" || :
[ "$1" == "scp" ]  && CMD="scp /backup/* scponly@dumpserver:incoming' username" || :
[ "$1" == "tape" ] && CMD='tar -cf /dev/st0 /backup/*' || :
[ "$CMD" == "" ]   && exit 1 || :
# make a backup
tar -zcvf  $FILE $DIRS
# Now depend upon circumstances run a backup command
$CMD
```

#### References

- [Bash shell script tip: Run commands from a variable](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-running-commands-from-a-variable.html)

Comment: This will run `C2` if `C1` fails, which violates the specification laid out in the question (namely, that only *one* of the commands is run). `x && y || z` is not equivalent to `if x; then y; else z; fi`.

Comment: @ChrisDown - see mods.

Comment: The edit nominally fixes this, but it's really obscure.  "If you're concerned with C1 having to fail so that C2 can run" doesn't capture the scenario at all.  The issue is that if `C1` is a command which sometimes returns a non-zero exit code, you will end up executing both `C1` and `C2` when that happens.

Comment: +1 but use `((...))` instead of `[...]` -- double parentheses are specifically for arithmetic expressions.

Comment: @glennjackman - thanks I've made the change.

Comment: One more simplification: you don't need `$(())` inside `(())` -- `(( RANDOM%2 == 0 ))`

Comment: @glennjackman - I see what you were suggesting now. Thanks. I've fixed it.